# signalr No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin

Tags: jquery, cors, signalr

I am implementing signalr in my application. I am getting **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin** error when connecting to the deployed **signalR hub.**

I need to use signalr hub in my application( localhost).

I have used below code :
HUB side:

```
app.Map("/signalr", map =>
            {
                // Setup the CORS middleware to run before SignalR.
                // By default this will allow all origins. You can 
                // configure the set of origins and/or http verbs by
                // providing a cors options with a different policy.
                map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);                
                var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
                {
                    // You can enable JSONP by uncommenting line below.
                    // JSONP requests are insecure but some older browsers (and some
                    // versions of IE) require JSONP to work cross domain
                    EnableJSONP = true,
                    EnableDetailedErrors = true,
                    EnableJavaScriptProxies= true
                };
                // Run the SignalR pipeline. We're not using MapSignalR
                // since this branch already runs under the "/signalr"
                // path.
                map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
            });
```

Config :

```
 <system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:64787/" />  
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />  
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />  
            <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

UI Side :

```
 // signalR integration
            var con = $.hubConnection('https://xxxx.azurewebsites.net/hub');

            con.logging = true;
            var hub = con.createHubProxy('hudHub');           

            con.starting(function () {

            });

            con.start()
                .done(function () {
                    alert('Connected');
                })
                .fail(function () {
                    alert('Failed connection');
                });
```

Error :

```
Failed to load https://xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/hub/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22hudhub%22%7D%5D&_=1524304303074: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:64787' is therefore not allowed access.
```